# POST to API from React frontend is not working -- Error 400

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, flask-restful

I'm trying to send data to my Flask API to get data into my database, but I keep getting the following error: OPTIONS /createUser HTTP/1.1" 400

**Reg.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';  

class Reg extends Component {  

  constructor() {  
    super();  

    this.state = {  
      FirstName: '',  
      LastName: '',  
      Email: '',  
      Password: '' 
    }  

    this.Email = this.Email.bind(this);  
    this.Password = this.Password.bind(this);  
    this.FirstName = this.FirstName.bind(this);  
    this.LastName = this.LastName.bind(this);   
    this.register = this.register.bind(this);  
  }  

  Email(event) {  
    this.setState({ Email: event.target.value })  
  }   

  Password(event) {  
    this.setState({ Password: event.target.value })  
  }  
  FirstName(event) {  
    this.setState({ FirstName: event.target.value })  
  }  
  LastName(event) {  
    this.setState({ LastName: event.target.value })  
  }  

  register(event) {  

    fetch('http://localhost:5000/createUser', {  
      method: 'post',  
      headers: {  
        'Accept': 'application/json',  
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' 
      },  
      body: JSON.stringify({  
        "FirstName": this.state.FirstName,  
        "Password": this.state.Password,  
        "Email": this.state.Email,  
        "LastName": this.state.LastName 
      })  
    }).then(function(res){
      return res.json();
    }).then(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }  

  render() {  

    return (  
      <div>  
        <form className="form" id="addItemForm">
            <input type="text"  onChange={this.FirstName} placeholder="Enter First Name"/>
            <input type="text"  onChange={this.LastName} placeholder="Enter Last Name"/>
            <input type="text"  onChange={this.Email} placeholder="Enter Email"/>
            <input type="password"  onChange={this.Password} placeholder="Enter Password"/>
            <button  onClick={this.register}  color="success" block>Create Account</button>
        </form>
      </div>  
    );  
  }  
}  

export default Reg;
```

**This is what my Flask API has**

```
@main.route('/createUser', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def createUser():
    conn = connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()

    req = request.get_json()
    first = req.get('FirstName')
    last = req.get('LastName')
    email = req.get('Email')
    pw = req.get('Password')

    sql = "INSERT INTO User (first, last, emailAddress, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
    data = (first, last, email, pw)
    cur.execute(sql, data)

    conn.commit()
    cur.close()

    return 'Done', 201
```

I've tried changing my JSON in case it was malformed, but it didn't change anything. I also tried posting from postman and it works fine from there so I'm thinking its the javascript.

Comment: try to use Axios for Http request in react js. you can refer to this [doc](https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/)

Comment: Your states' value should not be changing on event? Can you `console.log` them and post a snippet in here?

Comment: @Jawadulhassan where do I go about logging them?

Comment: Log them under render() and above return.

Comment: I'm wondering what the return type from the flask route is - you return simply "Done", 201 - that means most likely plain text, with 201 created. In your javascript, you try to parse JSON but you are not returning json.

Has your user been created?

Comment: @wiesson are you talking about the res.json() part?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add CORS extension if you are using Chrome and you should enable CORS in backend like springboot `@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:3000")`

Comment: I have CORS imported for flask and added CORS extension and it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in the block when you retrieve data from the request. 400 error is usually a sign of that server can't get values from your POST request body.

```
req = request.json
first = req['FirstName']
last = req['LastName']
```

Comment: I got the following error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

From your error message `error: OPTIONS /createUser HTTP/1.1" 400`, the `OPTIONS` request is not handled correctly. I guess, Postman is not doing a `OPTIONS` request by default, so that case works for you. In addition, the route is not returning any json, so `return res.json(); //error here` fails if it's plain text.

I have modified your example with plain Flask methods. Note: I have also removed the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'` request header from the Javascript.

```
@main.route('/createUser', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def createUser():
    # handle option request
    if request.method == "OPTIONS":
        response = make_response()
        response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
        response.headers[
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers"
        ] = "Origin, Accept, Content-Type"
        response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST,OPTIONS"
        response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = "true"
        return response

    if request.method == "POST":
        # do your SQL stuff
        conn = connection()
        cur = conn.cursor()

        req = request.get_json()
        first = req.get("FirstName")
        last = req.get("LastName")
        email = req.get("Email")
        pw = req.get("Password")

        sql = (
            "INSERT INTO User (first, last, emailAddress, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
        )
        data = (first, last, email, pw)
        cur.execute(sql, data)

        conn.commit()
        cur.close()

        # make response
        response = make_response("{}")  # return empty JSON response
        response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
        response.headers[
            "Content-Type"
        ] = "application/json"  # set response type to JSON
        return response

    return "", 405  # method not allowed
```

And please don't save passwords in plaintext in your database :-)

Comment: I changed it and nothing happens. Is it because my code for react is sending an OPTIONS request even though I specified it to be a POST (although I'm reading that it is because of CORS pre-flight request, which I don't entirely understand)?

Comment: The browser always sends an OPTION request before the "regular" (GET, POST, PUT..) request to check if the resource is allowed. What is the error message in the browser?

Comment: flask outputs "[13/Feb/2020 23:39:46] "OPTIONS /createUser HTTP/1.1" 200 ", but I log the states and they come out empty and nothing gets inserted into the database

Comment: The option request looks good to me - what happens inside the post method? Any logs from the browser?

Comment: The post request does not hit the server? You just see the options request? What does your Postman request say?

Comment: When I make a POST request through postman, the database changes successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can also trastically shorten your Code Part By using Name fields in your input Form Tags like `name=Email` and designing an universal change handler like so:

```
onChange(event) {  
    this.setState({ event.target.name: event.target.value })  
  }
```